# Ignore a multiple occurrence of a tag while comparing using xmlUnit

Tags: regex, xml, xmlunit

I have an XML file which looks like below.

Expected XML

```
<doc>
<tag>
    <file>a.c</file>
    <line>10</line>
    <type>c</type>
<tag>
<tag>
    <file>b.h</file>
    <line>14</line>
    <type>h</type>
<tag>
<tag>
    <file>d.he</file>
    <line>49</line>
    <type>he</type>
<tag>
</doc>
```

Now XML for testing

```
<doc>
<tag>
    <file>a1.c</file>
    <line>10</line>
    <type>c</type>
<tag>
<tag>
    <file>b1.h</file>
    <line>14</line>
    <type>h</type>
<tag>
<tag>
    <file>d1.he</file>
    <line>49</line>
    <type>he</type>
<tag>
</doc>
```

I want to compare this file with another XML file which has same structure.

I am using xmlUnit for comparison. While comparing I want to ignore XML tag `<file>`

Below is the comparison code which I wrote

```
public static Diff compareXML(String expXMLPath, String genXMLPath)
        throws IOException, SAXException {
    XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true);
    XMLUnit.setIgnoreAttributeOrder(true);
    final List<String> ignorableXPathsRegex = new ArrayList<String>();// list of regular expressions that custom difference listener used during xml 
    //comparison                                                                                
    ignorableXPathsRegex
            .add("\\/doc\\[1\\]\\/tag\\[1\\]\\/file\\[1\\]\\/text()");        
    Diff diff = null;
    try(FileInputStream fileStream1 = new FileInputStream(expXMLPath)) {
        try(FileInputStream fileStream2 = new FileInputStream(genXMLPath)) {
            InputSource inputSource1 = new InputSource(fileStream1);
            InputSource inputSource2 = new InputSource(fileStream2);
            diff = new Diff(inputSource1, inputSource2);
            RegDiffListener ignorableElementsListener = new RegDiffListener(
                    ignorableXPathsRegex);
            diff.overrideDifferenceListener(ignorableElementsListener);
            return diff;
        }
    }                
}
```

This is not working if XML file has more than one `<tag>...</tag>` block. I basically need a regex here which ignores all the `<file>` tag which are under `<doc><tag>`

I want the comparison of expected and test XML to show that both are same by ignoring the value of file tag, so `diff.similar()` should return `true`

Please suggest how to do it.

Comment: It would be easier to understand your goal if you added the expected result compared to your file structure.

Comment: I found the solution. ignorableXPathsRegex
            .add("\\/doc\\[1\\]\\/tag\\[1\\]\\/file\\[1\\]\\/text()"); tells to check only for the first tag. We should use ignorableXPathsRegex
            .add("\\/doc\\[1\\]\\/tag\\[\\d*\\]\\/file\\[1\\]\\/text()"); to ignore all the <file> inside all the <tag>

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
ignorableXPathsRegex .add("\\/doc\[1\]\\/tag\[1\]\\/file\[1\]\\/text()");
```

tells to check only for the first tag.

We should use

```
ignorableXPathsRegex .add("\\/doc\[1\]\\/tag\[\\d+\]\\/file\[1\]\\/text()");
```

to ignore all the `<file>` inside all the `<tag>`